# Algoritmo que crie uma fila em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, python-2.7

Olá, eu gostaria de criar um algoritmo porém não sei muito como começa-lo...

Seria para escrever um programa para criar uma fila, representada por uma lista, e apresentar ao usuário as opções de inserir, remover, obter a frente da fila e visualizar todo o conteúdo da fila, bem como uma opção para encerramento do programa.

E também seriam apenas números inteiros como elementos para serem armazenados na fila.

Alguém poderia me salvar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa pergunta ficou um pouco difícil de entender, mas vou tentar contextualizar. Espero que ajude. Em relação a fila, vou usar uma literal, com pessoas. Vou levar como algo básico por ser uma pergunta também de algoritmo.
Mais informações aqui no site da [devmedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460).

Vamos supor que já existem duas pessoas

```
pessoas = ['Keanan', 'Eduard']
```

---

Então acaba de chegar mais uma. Ela chegou por ultimo, então vai para o final

```
pessoas.append('Ayla')
```

Vai ficar algo assim: ['Keanan', 'Eduard', 'Ayla']

---

Prosseguindo... a fila finalmente andou, então o primeiro foi atendido. Logo ele sai da fila

```
pessoas.pop(0)
```

Ficando: ['Eduard', 'Ayla']
Aqui as coisas ficam realmente interessante. A gente tem vários jeitos de arrancas a pessoas da fila. Podemos chamar pelo nome dela, como em **pessoas.remove('Ayla')** ou pelo numero, como em **pessoas.pop(1)**. Também é possível usar **del pessoas[1](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460)**, sem parenteses nesse caso.

---

No final de tudo, o mais importante é lembrar que a contagem das listas começam em zero. Logo em ['Maisie', 'Smith', 'Hannah'] ou sou o [1](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460).
Para o primeiro elemento usamos [0], e o ultimo [-1].

---

Colinha:

```
idades = [10, 33, 5]
idades.append(3) # adiciona ao final
idades.pop(2) # remove o 5... o número dois é o indice
idades.remove(10) # remove o 10... o número dez é o valor
idades[0] # mostra o primeiro
idades[-1] # mostra o último

print(idades) # mostra todos
```

Aqui um exemplo de código que pode resolver o problema, não coloquei tudo pra deixar você pensar um pouco. Sobre o insert, ele coloca a pessoa em determinada posição na fila, com o 0 sendo o início.

```py
sair = False
fila = []

while not sair:
    entrada = int(input('''
Selecione uma opção:
  - [1] Adicionar
  - [2] Adicionar no Inicio
  - [3] Remover
  - [4] Ver Fila
  - [5] Sair \n 
'''))
    
    if entrada == 1:
    valor = input('O que deseja adicionar? ')
    fila.append(valor)
        
    if entrada == 2:
    valor = input('O que deseja adicionar ao inicio? ')
    fila.insert(0, valor)
        
    if entrada == 5:
    sair = True
```

Comment: Oi, então, a ideia seria criar um menu, e nele teriam as opções de inserir, remover, adicionar na frente da fila, visualizar todo o conteúdo da fila e repetir esse "menu" até selecionar a opção de finalizar o programa. Poderia por favor me ajudar a como fazer dessa forma?

Comment: vou editar a publicação

Answer (score 1):

A maneira comum de criar estruturas de dados em Python e outras linguagens mais modernas é utilizando classes, você pode criar uma classe para a fila e outra para os nos e dentro delas implementar métodos para gerenciar a fila. Dê uma olhada nesse artigo: https://algoritmosempython.com.br/cursos/algoritmos-python/estruturas-dados/filas/

Mas você também pode usar as listas comuns em python e com ela implementar uma fila gerenciando-a com os métodos da classe lista(pop, appende, insert, etc).

Mas caso você queira apenas criar um programa que usa a estrutura de dados fila, sem que você queira implementa-la, você pode importar de *collections*, *deque*, que já implementa uma a ED fila de maneira mais eficaz. Veja mais sobre deque aqui: https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

```
from collections import deque
```